# How do I use an SQL variable

Tags: css

I have a table where I have stored color hex codes which I fetch by ID from my SQL database. I then use the hex code as a variable to give color to my font in an other table based on values. My question is, can I use the hex code stored in the SQL database in CSS to color the text by using a class? The color of the text in the row is based on the value of a column in the table where the accounts are at. These are inserted and stored as numbers. Every row has one of the 15 color options in its row (if I am clear)

The part that gets the variable

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_name, cat_color FROM categories WHERE cat_ID = '".$obj->category."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$rij = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$cat_name = $rij->cat_name;  
$cat_color = $rij->cat_color;
```

The part that gives the tekst its color.

```
<td style="color:#<?= $cat_color ?> ", class="footer"><?= $rij->cat_name ?></td>
    <td style="color:#<?= $cat_color ?> ", class="footer"><?= $obj->sdb ?></td>
<td style="color:#<?= $cat_color ?> ",
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: @Dharman. Maybe I was not clear, but that I am asking here how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood. You need to hardcode your colors in CSS and then use the class names. If you really want to have dynamic colors then you need to use inline styling like you are already trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. It is not trying, this works allready. I am searching for a way to make it dynamic with CSS. Again i must have been inclear, i am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the color code into a `<style>` block:

```
<style>
.color-<?= $cat_name ?> {
  color:#<?= $cat_color ?>;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**N.B.** [`mysql`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) is deprecated since PHP 5.5 and has been removed in PHP 7, so you should replace it with [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (like in my example).

```
<?php
$host = '………'; # e.g. '127.0.0.1'
$dbname = '………'; # e.g. 'mydb'
$charset = '………'; # e.g. 'utf8mb4'
$username = '………'; # e.g. 'root'
$passwd = '………'; # e.g. 'mypasswd'
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=' . $charset;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = "SELECT `cat_name`, `cat_color`
  FROM `categories`
  WHERE `cat_ID` = :cat_ID;";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->bindParam(":cat_ID", $obj->category);
$statement->execute();
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
$categories = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  echo '<td style="color: #' . $category->cat_color . ';" class="footer">' . $category->cat_name . '</td>';
}
```